# How to signify before and after with an if else statement

Tags: python-3.x

I want to tell python that everything before a certain character in a string, equals something else. In this code, I want everything after the equals sign to be assigned to a separate list called results, and everything before the equals sign to be assigned to a whole other list called names.

I believe an if/else statement is needed, but I do not know how to signify BEFORE and AFTER in python.

```
lines = ['Data1         = 100',
         'Data2         = TRUE',
         'Data3         = 45',
         'Data4         = False',
         ]
```

Comment: First, create the two empty outputs lists you want: `results = []; names = []`. Then, you could use a python for-each loop (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop) over your input list `for line in lines:` and split the line at the equal sign, `temp_line = line.split("=")`. Go ahead and print `temp_line` out here and see what it looks like. Now append the proper element to each of your output lists. You may also want to `.strip()` the output so you don't have all those spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the list() function. Which splits the string into characters. Your problem with this is that you'll have to either specify the position on number of time the character appears before hand in order to get a start and stop location.

Another option is using the str.replace() if you know exactly what you want to replace, but both of these method present the problem that they are hard coded. If you're only wanting to replace them within a conditional statement, these could be useful.

For your use, you could say something like

```
    loop through array.
    split the element in the array using split
    add logic statement that if array[i-1] == "=", start replacing elements with new element
    then add the new element back into the array at the position you removed wanted to be removed.
```